# how to control SwipeRefreshLayout and Endless Fuction on Scroll StaggeredGrid RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, endlessscroll, staggeredgridlayout

I try commbine StaggeredGrid RecyclerView with Endless and SwipeRefreshLayout. but I have issue with my code :

```
grid.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
               super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
               int visibleItemCount = grid.getChildCount();
               int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
               int firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null)[0];
               if (firstVisibleItem == 0 && visibleItemCount > 0
                       && grid.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0) {
                   mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
               } else {
                   mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
               }
               mPreviousVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
               if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount
                       && totalItemCount != 0
                       && isFinishLoadingAwal
                       && !isFinishMoreNews
                       && adapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                   getMoreNewsFromServer();
               }
           }
       });
```

the code above, i get issue :

1. At endlessly position, `getMoreNewsFromServer();` always called (normal: one called).
2. At endlessly position, mSwipeRefreshLayout is called

if i used Listview, it's work like this :

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0 && visibleItemCount > 0
                        && list.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
                mPreviousVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount
                        && totalItemCount != 0
                        && isFinishLoadingAwal
                        && !isFinishMoreNews
                        && adapter.getCount() > 0) {
                    getMoreNewsFromServer();
                }
            }
        });
```

so how to fix it ?

Answer (score -1):

**first thing:**

> *"reach out where eyes can not reach"*

```
onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
```

so replace **list - >** with **view** in code fragment:

```
   && list.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0
```

**second:**

it is risky to use mSwipeRefreshLayout without take care to check if it is not null!
u can try to inser at beginning onScroll() {

```
if (mSwipeRefreshLayout == null) {
   mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id...);
} else { .. }
```

**third:**

don't you experience of a [refresh bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181873) ? but maybe users of your app do ?